# Protractor: Else statement isn't working as expected

Tags: if-statement, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to click on a link if it exists, if not it should add that corresponding link and then click on the same.

In below If loop, 'Else' condition is not getting executed if first condition is not satisfied. The same is working if its placed outside IF loop.

I'm confused.

Could anyone help me out in resolving this please ?

```
var ConfigLink = element.all(by.partialLinkText('Provide Configuration')).get(0);

        ConfigLink.isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
        if (result) {
                ConfigLink.click();
        } 

        else {
                element.all(by.css('input[name="checks"]')).get(0).click();
        }

        });
```

If the initial If condition fails , I want the script to execute the else part, but this is not working.

kindly suggest how this can be resolved Thank you

Comment: Found the solution myself. Replaced 'isDisplayed()' with 'isPresent()' and it worked seamlessly.

Comment: Please answer your question. Also, please clarify what you are doing to loop through. This might help other people if they encounter the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: @cnishina : I was trying to click on a link only if it exists (If part of the loop). if not,it should do the steps mentioned in Else part of the loop. However, it was not going into the Else part since the issue was with isDisplayed() (not sure why it didn't work though). I had replaced isDisplayed() with 'isPresent()' and the code seems to be working fine now without any issues.

Comment: That makes sense. Is displayed assumes that the element is already present. If the element is not present, an error should be thrown. If you chained your function like: `ConfigLink.isDisplayed().then((result => { ... }).catch(err => { console.log(err) });` you would see the error.

Comment: Also, since you answered your own question, please provide an official StackOverflow answer. It'll help other viewers to know this has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Its done @cnishina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Replaced isDisplayed() with 'isPresent()' and the code seems to be working fine now without any issues. This makes sense since, isDisplayed() assumes that the element is already present. If the element is not present, an error should be thrown.